# ansible win_copy failed to copy from linux source to windows destination

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

i try to copy file from local (the ansible controller Linux server ) file to windows server destination 
but it has error :

```
2020-05-09 07:31:31,392 p=17343 u=ec2-user n=ansible | task path: /home/app/ansible/roles/utilities/tasks/download_package_win.yml:41
2020-05-09 07:31:31,392 p=17343 u=ec2-user n=ansible | Saturday 09 May 2020  07:31:31 +0000 (0:00:03.544)       0:04:22.262 **********
2020-05-09 07:31:31,423 p=17642 u=ec2-user n=ansible | Using module file /home/app/venv_python3/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/windows/win_copy.ps1
2020-05-09 07:31:31,423 p=17642 u=ec2-user n=ansible | Pipelining is enabled.
2020-05-09 07:31:31,425 p=17642 u=ec2-user n=ansible | <10.0.3.64> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: Administrator on PORT 5986 TO 10.0.3.64
2020-05-09 07:31:31,543 p=17642 u=ec2-user n=ansible | EXEC (via pipeline wrapper)
2020-05-09 07:31:32,718 p=17343 u=ec2-user n=ansible | fatal: [10.0.3.64]: FAILED! => changed=false
  dest: c:/my_app_home/
  msg: 'Cannot copy src file: ''/home/app/1//de85cfa1-cb41-53ca-aba0-0e3dd728c27b//test.zip'' as it does not exist'
  src: /home/app/backup/1//de85cfa1-cb41-53ca-aba0-0e3dd728c27b//test.zip
```

although the file do exist:

```
ls -l /home/app/1//de85cfa1-cb41-53ca-aba0-0e3dd728c27b//test.zip
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 584015456 May  9 07:31 /home/app/1//de85cfa1-cb41-53ca-aba0-0e3dd728c27b//test.zip
```

this is the module :

```
- name: Copy file to windows remote
      win_copy :
        src: "/home/app/backup/1//de85cfa1-cb41-53ca-aba0-0e3dd728c27b//test.zip"
        dest: "c:/my_app_home/"
        remote_src: yes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use backslashes for the Windows path. Also, `remote_src` should be `no` because the file is on local.

```
- name: Copy file to windows remote
      win_copy :
        src: "/home/app/backup/1//de85cfa1-cb41-53ca-aba0-0e3dd728c27b//test.zip"
        dest: "c:\my_app_home\"
        remote_src: no
```